# Código não compila em C++11

Tags: windows, c++11, time, gcc, mingw

Eu tenho um código comum, mais especificamente o seguinte:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>

namespace thread
{
    void check_key(sf::Keyboard::Key key)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(key))
            {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    sf::Thread keycheck(&thread::check_key, sf::Keyboard::Escape);
    keycheck.launch();
    while(true)
        std::cout << "Hello! ";
}
```

E quando compilo no Code::Blocks, com o Wizzard do SFML 2.0, funciona corretamente (sai quando aperto ESC). Fui trocar o `sf::Thread` pelo `std::thread` e claro: primeiro ativei o C++11. Só para ver se rodava, tentei compilar. O MinGW devolveu vários erros de, por exemplo, `::diftime` e outras entidades apenas do `<ctime>`. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Tem como dar mais detalhes do erro? E qual compilador você está usando? Eu já vi algumas versões do gcc (principalmente as anteriores ao 4.8.0) que dava muito erro com C++11.

Comment: @LucasNunes GCC (MinGW) 4.8.1. Descobri que o problema não é SFML, mas realmente o <ctime> + C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era, provavelmente, um arquivo corrompido. A solução é desinstalar o compilador e instalá-lo novamente.